# Get exit status of command substitution

Tags: shell-script, zsh, command-substitution, exit-status

If I assign the output of a command substitution to a local variable, how do I get the exit status of the command?

This is the behaviour of ZSH 5.8:

```
false; echo $? # output is 1 as expected

foo=$(false); echo $? # output is 1 as expected

local foo=$(false); echo $? # output is 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the declaration from the assignment:

```
local foo
foo=$(false)
```

(See also [SC2155](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2155).)

Comment: Also `local foo=$(false) status=$?` works to save the exit status of the subshell